# Filter a given List based on external List in Linq in one query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce

I've a list :

```
List<Student> lstStudents = GetConditionalStudents();
```

I've another list:

```
List<School> allSchools  = dbContext.Schools.ToList();
```

Every School has list of Students

```
public class School
{
   ///other properties
   public List<Student> {get;set;}
}
```

I'am forced to do this:

```
List<School> schools = from p in allSchools
                       where p.LocationId==this.LocationId
                       where p.Students.Any(d=>lstStudents.Contains(d))
                       select p;
```

but it doesn't work: gives error

```
unable to create a constant value for .. only primitive types
```

## Edit

I can make it work by doing this:

```
List<int> integers = lstStudents.Select(s=>s.Id).ToList();
List<School> schools = from p in allSchools
                       where p.LocationId == this.LocationId
                       where p.Students.Any(d=>integers.Contains(d.Id))
                       select p;
```

but I don't want to use it, coz I hav situations where I have to compare more than 2 Ids, so that implies, I will have to make more than 2 separate `primitive datatype List` and use them in the query,which I don't want.

how to directly use the external list in the linq query.??

I cannot use this:

```
allSchools.Where(s=>s.LocationId==this.LocationId ||
lstStudents.Contains(s)).ToList();
```

Please help...
I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535552/building-an-external-list-while-filtering-in-linq) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862491/unable-to-create-a-constant-value-only-primitive-types)..but they are no help to me..

Comment: @ChrisSincliar ..lstStudents gets populated with proper list of students. it has proper records

Comment: Yeah sorry, I just noticed that, sorry!

Comment: Is this using Linq2Entities?

Comment: :) Entity-Framework Code First

Comment: how is allSchools related to lstStudents  is there an id they share

Comment: allSchools is a list of School and every School has list of Students . many-to-many relationship. thts how they are related

Comment: Could you show us the code for GetConditionalStudents method?

Comment: You might consider replacing the expression `p.Students.Any(d=>lstStudents.Contains(d))` with `p.Students.Intersect(lstStudents).Any()`.

Comment: I did tht Timothy. it gave me same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
var schools = from p in allSchools
              where (p.LocationId==this.LocationId && p.Students.Any(s => lstStudents.Contains(s)))
              select p;
```

Comment: it gave me this error :"Internal .NET Framework Data Provider error 1025."

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the Entity Framework is unable to translate your list of students into a valid SQL statement - obviously the database server knows nothing about you `Student` class and therefore the Entity Framework can not translate the LINQ query into something the database server could understand. There are three solutions.

1. Get rid of your method `GetConditionalStudents()` and directly include the query building this list in the main query if possible.
2. Fetch both lists - `lstStudents` and `allSchools` - into memory by calling `ToList()` on the respective queries and process both lists using LINQ to Objects.
3. Use object IDs instead of the objects because the Entity Framework is able to translate lists of integers, strings and so on into a `IN` statement.

To me it looks like you are already doing option two but obviously you are not because the code fails but I am unable to pin the exact flaw.

Comment: @Daniel, soul purpose of GetConditionalStudents() is to simplify the question structure. problem lies in usage of external list. Though initially I started with just one query. Option 3, is working but only when I 'Select' all the Ids outside the query in a separate list and then compare, but not inside.